# How do save slots work in in Blood Dragon?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

I want to play two games of Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon without one overwriting the other.

The New Game screen shows three save slots:
[image: Blood Dragon - New Game]

The Load Game screen shows six slots, three of which appear to be autosave slots:
[image: Blood Dragon - Load Game]

My suspicion is that the save slots and autosave slots are paired. If I make a new game in "Save 2", it will autosave to "Autosave 2", and when I manually save, it will go to "Save 2".

Is my understanding correct?